# Save Data In A Method of @EventListener or @TransactionalEventListener

Tags: spring

Based on an article, [Better application events in Spring Framework 4.2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2), I set up all related classes. The most of my code works as desired with an exception in a method of a listener.

The controller:

```
@PostMapping("/Foos")
public ResponseEntity<Foo> handle(@RequestBody Foo foo){
    Optional<Foo> f = fooService.save(foo);
    return f.isPresent() ?  new ResponseEntity<>(f, HttpStatus.OK) :
            new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

The service:

```
@Transactional
public Optional<Foo> save(Foo foo){
    foo = fooRepository.save(foo);
    publisher.publishEvent(new FooEvent(foo));
    return Optional.of(foo);
}
```

Without @Transcational in the above method, the following method won't be triggered.

The Listener

```
@Async
@TransactionalEventListener(condition ="#event.ok", phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
public void handle(FooEvent event){
    Product product = new Product(event.getData());
    productService.save(product);
}
```

The ProductService

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Optional<Product> save(Product product){
    product = productRepository.save(product);
    return Optional.of(product);
}
```

The Product data isn't saved at all although the listener method is invoked. The code is run in a Spring Boot app BTW. I haven't found any related information online yet. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check that method is triggered? If you configured transation in wrong way this method  doen't call

Comment: The method is called. I have a println in the method.

Comment: what is transaction propagation level for save ? and do you sure AFTER_COMMIT is what you need?  why not  BEFORE_COMMIT ?

Comment: What do you think `@TransactionalEventListener` is? Hint it isn't about an event listener being transactional. With that said just add `@Transactional` to the event listener.

Comment: @sbjavateam  I used the default propagation level. The reason I use AFTER_COMMIT is to ensure the event is detected only after the another object is saved successfully.

Comment: @M.Deinum As I mentioned, the method is invoked, but the product data isn't saved.

Comment: @vic then you need use required_new propagation and - it will be  actualy ' another object is saved successfully' in current transaction

Comment: I see @Bohdan Levchenko already answered on this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution might be different depending on what you want to achieve:

1. If you want to save product within the scope of **existing** transaction (where you published an event) then just change the phase to `TransactionPhase.BEFORE_COMMIT` and you should be good.
2. If you want to save product within the **new** independent transaction just after the previous one then add a `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` to your handle method and left everything else as is.

Comment: After doing one more test, the both approach does work. Thanks.

Comment: it also works when I add `@async` annotation instead of `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`
 normally we can save a new entity without @Transactional annotation.
it seems that there is an issue here. `TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT` doesn't repair the thread context to its initial state after the commit operation I guess.